# Finding the dimension of subspace span(S)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Problem:

Consider the set of vectors $S= \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ where
$a_1= (6,4,1,-1,2)$
$a_2 = (1,0,2,3,-4)$
$a_3= (1,4,-9,-16,22)$
$a_4= (7,1,0,-1,3)$

Find the dimension of the subspace $span(S)$?

- I know that dimension is the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in a subspace.
- So is the dimension in this case 4? Since there are 4 vectors?

Find a set of vectors in $S$ that forms basis of $span(S)$?

- How do I solve this?

Comment: You're close.  The maximum possible dimension of the subspaces spanned by these vectors is 4; it can be less if $S$ is a linearly dependent set of vectors.  The basis for $Span(S)$ will be the maximal subset of linearly independent vectors of $S$ (i.e. $S$ after removing vectors that can be written as a linear combination of the others).

Comment: @Hayden thanks for replying. Okay so dimension could be for. How do I determine if one or more vectors is lin combo of the others? Guess and check?

Comment: One method would be to suppose that there was a linear combination $c_1a_1+c_2a_2+c_3a_3+c_4a_4=0$.  This will give you homogeneous system of linear equations.  You can then row reduce the matrix to find out the rank of the matrix, and the dimension of the subspace will be equal to this rank.

Comment: @Hayden okay so I did that and I got  c1= -t c2 = 5t c3 = t c4 = 0 What does this mean?

Comment: You misunderstand. Showing that the equation provided by Hayden has only the trivial solution is equivalent to showing that the set is linearly independent.

Comment: @Hayden  I know, they are linearly independent. What I am wondering is that if they are linearly independent does that mean dimension = 4? Since they cannot be written as linear combination?

Comment: Yes, if they are linearly independent then the dimension is four.  As shown in RecklessReckoner's answer, they are not linearly independent, since the rank is 3.

Comment: @Hayden so dimension is 3 and they are not linearly independent?

Comment: @Hayden also which set of the vectors in S is basis for Span(S)?

Answer (score 7):

Write your four vectors as column vectors of a $ \ 5 \times 4 \ $ matrix and row reduce it:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 6 & 1 & 1 &7 \\4&0&4&1\\1&2&-9&0\\-1&3&-16&-1\\2&-4&22&3 \end{array} \right)  \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&-3&16&1\\0&1&-5&\frac{1}{2} \end{array} \right) $$

[I used the fourth row here to work against the other rows; that doesn't matter particularly.]

What does the "zeroing-out" of two rows tell us?  How can we use what non-zero rows remain to construct a basis for span(S) ? (Notice that these are *five*-dimensional vectors, so we are already starting out "short a coordinate variable", making it "free".)

**EDIT --** Since the discussion has advanced further, we can say something about the basis of span(S).  Taking the hint from **Omnomnomnom** or the above, the subspace spanned by your set of four vectors only has dimension 3.  So we need to set up three linearly independent vectors, using the columns of the row-reduced matrix.

We could "reduce" those last two rows a bit more to obtain

$$  \rightarrow \ \ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&-5&0 \end{array} \right) \ \ . $$

With the matrix fully "reduced", we need to pick out three (five-dimensional) column vectors which are linearly independent.  The third column is a linear combination of the first two, so we can toss that one out.  A suitable basis for span(S) is then

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 \\0\\1\\0\\0 \end{array} \right) \ \ , \ \ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 \\0\\0\\1\\0 \end{array} \right) \ \ , \ \ \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 \\0\\0\\0\\1 \end{array} \right) \ \  . $$

Comment: While a valid deduction can certainly be made by counting the "zeroed out rows", I'd like to point out that it is more common to count the leading $1$s, corresponding to the (column-) rank of the matrix and hence the...

Comment: that they are linearly independent, you'd have no way to solve for the k values in k1v1 + .... + k4v4 = 0 so you'd have to assign a parameter like t or s ect.

Comment: So does that mean dimension is 4? @RecklessReckoner

Comment: Okay so with the zeroing out the dimension is 3. Also, which set of vectors is a basis for Span(S)? a1-a4? Or only a certain number of the vectors? @RecklessReckoner

Comment: @RecklessReckoner so then the vectors {a1,a2,a3} form basis for Span(S)?

Comment: I don't think so: the row-reduction on the first three columns "clears out" all the entries of the first three rows.  The fourth column vector has a component not found in the "reduction" of the first three, so the fourth vector is needed, and we can toss out the third, as shown above.  You could use $  \ \mathbb{a}_1, \mathbb{a}_2, \mathbb{a}_4 \ $ or the basis I gave. (Note that the first two components of the vectors can be _anything_, since they are "meaningless" in the subspace $ \ S \ $ , which is a [three-dimensional] $ \ x_3 \ x_4 \ x_5 \ $ space.)

Answer (score 0):

I think colormegone's procedure to find basis is correct in terms of row reducing the matrix. However I don't think his statement that the set of $$\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ is a basis is true. Because a basis should be able to represent any vector in the vector space with linear combination, but if we take $a1 = \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 4 \\ 1 \\ −1 \\2 \end{pmatrix}$, there's no way to use linear combination of vectors in the above set to represent it.

These 3 vectors correspond to the first, second and fourth column in the original matrix, so a basis (or one possible set of basis) should be the set of corresponding column vectors in the original matrix, i.e. $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}6 \\ 4 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ -4\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 7 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$